# How can I access an element in a loaded iframe?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, dom, iframe, modal-dialog

I have a website with a donorbox button. When it's clicked, an iframe is added to the page as a modal. I want to access the elements in that iframe but I get an error `Cannot read property 'click' of null` when I try to click one of the buttons with a simple `document.getElementsByClassName('db_button')[0].click();` command.

Debugging in the console, I also get the same message until I inspect the element and then it seems to work fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

firstly, get your iframe element

`document.getElementById('iframeId')` or `document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")`

the second expression will get a list object, get the iframe you need with index.

secondly, get inner document by this

`a.contentDocument || a.contentWindow.document`

then do your search inside iframe's document.

Comment: Thanks for this. But I get an "Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin ___ from accessing a cross-origin frame" error when trying to access the inner document.

Comment: if your iframe load third-party url content, it's called cross-origin. you can't get inner document from outside because this might cause security problem.

reference this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame

try other ways to do what you want! if you have to do so, not consider security, use reverse-proxy to load third-party site with same url as your main site to cheat browser!

Comment: So there's no way to click an element in the iframe?